# JQM popup - fieldcontain doesn't work inside popup

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup

I'm using Jquery mobile popup and want to display a form in a popup.
I want to display the text label and text box in the same line. So, I use div with fieldcontain around it.
It works outside of popup but not inside.

```
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="input"> Fieldname </label>
        <input type="text" id="input" value="" />
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="input"> Fieldname   </label>                                                
    <input type="text" id="input" value="" />
</div>
```

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B3pyG/

I wonder if this is a limitation of popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Field Containers are hampered by the styling used for Popups. I tried with their Form example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/BrsR2/

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Test PopUp</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>
        <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
            <form>
                <div style="padding:10px 20px; width: 440px">
                    <h3>Please sign in</h3>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="un">Username:</label>
                        <input placeholder="username" id="un" value="" name="user">
                        <label for="pw">Password:</label>
    <input id="pw" type="password" placeholder="password" value="" name="pass">
                    </div>
                    <div data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-icon="" data-iconpos="" data-theme="b" aria-disabled="false">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
             <label for="input"> Fieldname </label>
             <input type="text" id="input" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Popup wrapper seems to pull everything in and wrap as much as it can. They talk about it in documentation:

> The popup consists of two elements: the screen, which is a transparent
>   or translucent element that covers the entire document, and the
>   container, which is the popup itself. If your original element had an
>   id attribute, the screen and the container will each receive an id
>   attribute based on it. The screen's id will be suffixed with
>   "-screen", and the container's id will be suffixed with "-popup" (in
>   the above example, id="popupBasic-screen" and id="popupBasic-popup",
>   respectively).
>
> The framework adds a small amount of margin to text elements, but it's
>   really just a container with rounded corners and a shadow which serves
>   as a blank slate for your designs (even these features can be disabled
>   via [options](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/options.html)).

You could get around this by making a box for the label and floating the Input the right. Something like:

```
<span display="width: 100%; display: block;">
    <span style="display: inline-block; width: 100px;">Label: </span>
    <input type="text" name="test" style="width: 340px; float: right;">
</span>
```

Comment: Yes, that workaround works fine. 
I also tried to use popupafteropen event to add the form elements. But the style formatting didn't take effect. I wish there was a refresh method for fieldcontain.
However, your workaround solves the problem.

Comment: I haven't seen one. Can try something like `.page("create")`.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is 3 years ago, but just a suggestion, perhaps you could use a table within a popup?